# How can we extract duplicate values from multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset regarding Big Mart sales.
(You can find it here)
https://www.kaggle.com/brijbhushannanda1979/bigmart-sales-data

In the dataset there are columns like 'Outlet_Location_Type' and 'Outlet_Size'.
I want to find how many Tier1 locations have Medium 'Outlet_Size' and want to visualize this using grouped bar chart.I need a pythonic solution to this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to include some kind of summary of the structure of the data-set in the question. The question will become meaningless if/when the link gets deleted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the method of framing questions on stack overflow.This is my first question.Anyways thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `groupby` method :

```
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
df = df[df['Outlet_Location_Type']=='Tier 1'].groupby(['Outlet_Size']).count()
```

Each column is equal and contains the number of element so you can select one randomly to plot the count :

```
df['Item_Identifier'].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can validate the answer if it solve your problem. Thanks